# How to correctly set up a object in JSON in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json

I want to map a key "coordinate" to an object with two key-value pairs which are a key of "latitude" mapping to the integer 50 and a key "longitude" mapping to the integer 60.

```
"coordinate" : [{
    "latitude": 50, "longitude": 60
}]
```

My question is this the correct way to set up an object in JSON in JavaScript because I keep getting error or typo at "coordinate"?

Comment: It's an array containing an object. Remove the `[ ]` if you want only an object

Comment: But what's the error? Knowing what "an error" is would be helpful

Comment: JSON is a serialzation format, a String. You have Objects (in whatever language you're using) and you serialize them into a JSON *(-string)*

Comment: I found the error. You were right I need to remove the [ ].

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the below code to initialize the key value pair in object

```js
var sampleObject = {"coordinate" : [{
    "latitude": 50, "longitude": 60
}]}

console.log(sampleObject)
```